# java selection sort using single array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have written  a java code for selection sort by using and manipulating in the same array. But I'm not getting sorted array as output. Tell me the corrections in my below given code.plz help thankyou

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class SS
{
int a[]={2,4,7,1,3};
int min=a[0],temp,x=0,m;
void swap(int p,int q)
{
temp=a[p];
a[p]=a[q];
a[q]=temp;
}

void ssort()
{
int n=a.length;

for(m=-1; m<n; m++)
{m=m+1;
for(int i=m;i<n;i++)
{
if(a[i]<min)
{
min=a[i];
x=i;
}
}
swap(m,x);

}


for(int k=0;k<=n;k++)
{
System.out.print(a[k]+"  ");
}
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

SS obj=new SS();
obj.ssort();
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `Arrays.sort(a);`

Answer (score 1):

Check your code, you did a couple of mistakes, here the right code with some tips:

- Pass the array to sort as a parameter
- Use the right indentation to better read your code
- define variables only when needed
- don't use instance variables but only variables locales to the method

Here the code:

```
void ssort(int[] a) {
    for (int m = 0; m < a.length; m++) { 
        int min = m;
        for (int i = m + 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[min]) {
                posmin = i;
            }
        }
        int temp = a[m];
        a[m] = a[min];
        a[min] = temp;
    }
}
```

Note: I used the same names of your variables. Check it because it is possible that there are typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wont to use Arrays.sort(a).
you can use this

```
void ssort() {
    bubbleSort(a);
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
public static void bubbleSort(int [] array) {

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {

            if(array[j]>array[j+1]) {
                int k = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = k;
                flag=true;
            }


        }

        if(!flag) break; 
    }
}
```